# WSL: windows executable giving segmentation faults in certain directories

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I can't successfully run any windows command from certain directories. These are Windows directories, not native WSL directories.

```
$ cd /mnt/f/Projects/ng/standalone2/
# no error:
$ explorer.exe .
$ cd /mnt/f/Projects/ng/android2/
$ explorer.exe .
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I've tried using `icacls.exe` to erase any ICLs that could have been causing the problem. Newly created directories sometimes exhibit the problem, so I can't just copy everything and expect it to work from that point forward. I can't even run "git.exe help clone" (and I can't totally get away from using Windows executables).

How can I debug this? I am using Windows 10, version 1909 (build 18363.720).

Comment: Did you use latest fixed version 3.0.1.2? Did you add any `/etc/wsl.conf` file to configure settings? Try to use chmod and chown to fix WSL side. DO NOT use icacls or takeown.

Comment: I upgraded wsltty but that did not fix the problem. And why do you tell people not to use icacls? I would have had to trash this computer multiple times if not for the saving hand of icacls. Chown/chmod do absolutely nothing when the windows side is broken. And I have `options = "metadata"` in wsl.conf. I used to have bind mounts and drives mounted in multiple places, but I removed those settings.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Right, I don't use WSL files at all, except for config and scripts. Thanks for mentioning this to the developer! Though I've found a workaround, something weird is going on (and it may be a WSL bug).

Comment: I and wsltty dev both tried. No issue at all. Try to reset or reinstall your wsl distro and wsltty.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Thank you. Of course it's partially an environment issue, but I don't know how to pinpoint it. Thanks anyway.